# Progress bar, dialog jquery ui работает только в мазиле, как исправить

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!
progress bar, dialog из jquery ui работает только в мазилле, но не в других браузерах.
Вот так я его инициализирую при щелчке на кнопке:

```
        $("#progress_bar").dialog(
            {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                modal: true,
                title: "Запуск тестов...",
                close: function( event, ui ) {alert("meow")},
                autoOpen:false,
            });

    $("#progress_bar").progressbar({
        value: false
    });
```

Вот это происходит при удачном ответе ajax-запроса:

```
 $('#progress_bar').progressbar("destroy");
```

Сам контейнер для модульного окна:

```
  <div id="progress_bar"></div>
```

Помогите, подскажите почему в других браузерах модульное окно не появляется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что синхронно работала отправка ajax-запроса.